# Topological intuition for the cancellation property of separated maps w.r.t a class of properties of continuous maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, intuition, geometric-intuition

Recall a continuous map is *separated* if its diagonal is closed. This is equivalent to the fibers being relatively Hausdorff in the total space.

**Proposition.** Suppose $\mathrm P$ is a class of continuous maps satisfying the following conditions.

- Closed under composition.
- Stable under pullback.
- Contains closed topological embeddings.

Then $g\circ f$ lies in $\mathrm P$ and $g$ is separated, then $f$ has $\mathrm P$.

*Proof.* Form the obvious pullback diagrams and play around.

**Question.** What is the topological intuition behind this proposition? How does the separation property of fibers somehow allow to "cancel" separated maps?